# styles applied to Horizontal Line via css file is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-pasteur-ntcuj

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const separator = {
    backgroundColor: "#E9E9E9",
    height: "12px",
    margin: "8px",
    borderRadius: "4px"
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <hr style={separator} />
      <hr className="line-separator" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.line-separator {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

styles applied via java script is working fine but the same is not working from `css` for `<hr />` tag.

Answer (score 3):

**Your className is wrong.**
try: `<hr className="line-separator" />`

You have another Typo in your CSS, your **height** should be **12px** not 2px

Comment: Sorry, I just made some typo. But your answer also not work kindly check the above link.

Comment: dunno if you get a notif when i edit my awnser, so here you go :D

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in setting className of the second hr as "separator". It should match the className specified in the css file.

Correct code:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const separator = {
    backgroundColor: "#E9E9E9",
    height: "12px",
    margin: "8px",
    borderRadius: "4px"
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <hr style={separator} />
      <hr className="line-separator" />
    </div>
  );
}
.line-separator {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just made some typo. But your answer also not work kindly check the above link.

Answer (score 0):

this should be a super quick fix:

Your className needs to match the name of the css class `.line-separator`

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const separator = {
    backgroundColor: "#E9E9E9",
    height: "12px",
    margin: "8px",
    borderRadius: "4px"
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <hr style={separator} />
      <hr className="line-separator" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `height` value here just needs changing to `12px`

```css
.line-separator {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just made some typo. But your answer also not work kindly check the above link.

Comment: I've just copy/pasted the code from this answer into your example and it looks to work fine (remember to save). https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-haze-kv1yu